# Modify the value of network.http.accept-encoding using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to modify the about:config value of network.http.accept-encoding from gzip, deflate to identity using javascript before I make a web request.

Comment: I hope JavaScript cannot alter those values, actually.

Comment: In what context do you want to do that?  In some script in a web page? If so, it cannot be done.

Comment: Imagine the chaos if internal settings like that could be changed with just some javascript. Hit a random malicious page, get your 'network.proxy.http' changed to `hackme.com` and then go do some online banking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change `Accept-Encoding`. Firefox, at least, will block this header from being set through ajax.

What you could do, however, is send your AJAX or web request through a servlet filter which changes the header of the request before continuing on.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox won't let you change settings from JavaScript (at least not on a webpage).

But, depending on what you want to do, you might be able to try using HttpRequest (AJAX) and setting the Accept-Encoding header yourself. I don't know if it lets you override that header or not, and you would be limited to the same domain the page is from (or, with newer versions, domains that explicitly allow cross-domain requests).